# How to curry two closures in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a Java method:

```
void copy(Object src, Object dest);
```

I am using it in Groovy as such:

```
def copyGroovy = { p1, p2 -> copy(p1,p2) }
def copyFixP1 = { p1 -> copyGroovy.curry(p1) }
def cp = // How to define this?
```

How can I write the invocation in Groovy so that it looks like:

```
cp src dest
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write the invocation with space separated arguments like you would in Haskell (or other functional languages). Instead you need to write:

```
copyFixP1(src)(dst)
```

Also, you called the second variable as `copyFixP1` but you are not actually fixing `p1`, `copyFixP1` still needs an argument. Fixing would be to explicitly set the first argument of `copyGroovy` let's say to `'sourcePath'` like so:

```
def copyFixedSrc = copyGroovy.curry('sourcePath')
```

You did curry it however so `copyFixP1` is what I assume you wanted as `cp`.

Comment: It seems that argument lists need to be comma separated in groovy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a DSL like command chain you can take advantage of passing arguments without parentheses and/or dot notation. The closest form of `cp` command you mentioned in the question is something like:

```
cp (src) (dest)
```

`cp` in this case is a function that returns a closure that calls your Java's `copy(Object src, Object dest)` method. Something like this:

```
def cp(src) {
    return { dest ->
        copy(src, dest)
    }
}
```

If you would like to get rid of parentheses and you accept additional keyword, you could get something like this:

```
copy src to dest
```

which is an equivalent of:

```
copy(src).to(dest)
```

`copy` method can be implemented as:

```
def copy(src) {
    [to: { dest ->
        copy(src, dest)
    }]
}
```

And last, but not least - you can actually call this Java method as:

```
copy src, dest
```

You get rid of parentheses, but you need to add `,` to tell the compiler that you pass two arguments to this function.

#### Example

Below you can find example of all 3 combinations:

```
void copy(Object src, Object dest) {
    println "Copying ${src} to ${dest}..."
}

def copy(src) {
    [to: { dest ->
        copy(src, dest)
    }]
}

def cp(src) {
    return { dest ->
        copy(src, dest)
    }
}

def src = "/tmp/test.txt"
def dest = "/tmp/test2.txt"

// Example 1
copy src to dest

// Example 2
cp (src) (dest)

// Example 3
copy src, dest
```

Running this script produces following output:

```
Copying /tmp/test.txt to /tmp/test2.txt...
Copying /tmp/test.txt to /tmp/test2.txt...
Copying /tmp/test.txt to /tmp/test2.txt...
```

> *You can read more about Groovy DSL features [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.12/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html)*

Answer (score 2):

The following is a DSL answer that is arguably more of a kludge to solve a puzzle: it does not address currying syntax, but provides the veneer of `cp src dest`. But I hope it illustrates some Groovy features.

If we begin with the copy functions:

```
class Copy { 
    def copy = { a, b -> println "TRACER copy ${a} to ${b}" }
    def copyGroovy = { p1, p2 -> copy(p1,p2) }
    def copyFixP1 = { p1 -> copyGroovy.curry(p1) }
}
```

and define a `Copier` with some meta-programming methods:

```
class Copier {
    def copyContext 
    def runContext
    def p1, p2

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        p1 = args[0]
        return this
    }

    Object getProperty( String property ) {
        p2 = runContext.getProperty(property)
        copyContext.copyFixP1(p1)(p2)
    }
}
```

Then consider the following (assuming a single Groovy script as shown [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_34_stack_overflow_50630886)):

```
// ----- main 

class Example {
    def src = "A"
    def dest = "B"

    def run = { ->
        def cp = new Copier(copyContext: new Copy(), runContext: this)

        // at long last:
        cp src dest
    }
}

new Example().run()
```

Comment: Note that another example at the link provided cleans up to this `def cp = new Copier(new Copy(), this)`. It is essentially the same though.